# Polygonal surface reconstruction

Tags: polygon, cgal, surface, 3d-reconstruction

I want to reconstruct a surface from a point cloud of xyz points only, but the example provided requires a normal for each point. I have 2 questions: 1) what does the normal represent. 2) what do I do if I don't have the normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a point cloud that represent a surface, the associated normal is the normal direction on the surface at the point. If you don't have such normals, CGAL provides some methods to estimate and orient those normals:
[`pca_estimate_normals()`](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessing3Algorithms.html#ga8c642da96a025ab32445aeb6cc219b0b) or [`jet_estimate_normals()`](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessing3Algorithms.html#ga0cd0f87de690d4edf82740e856efa491)  for the estimation and [mst_orient_normals()](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Point_set_processing_3/group__PkgPointSetProcessing3Algorithms.html#ga50c98d5c5ae5535bce6f32eddbd03f33) for the orientation.

Note that the links I'm giving are for the upcoming 5.1 release but the functions exist in previous releases. You can also read the new reconstruction tutorial [here](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html).

Comment: Thanks for that. Since posting the question I tried using pca_estimate_normals() to no avail. i think my understanding of the input point cloud is flawed - the points I'm providing represent a matrix of internal and external points. I am attempting to filter just the external ones.

Comment: I am attempting to filter just the external points to get the concave hull of a building.